# Group users by month for last year in Lucid

Tags: group-by, knex.js, adonis.js, lucid

I am working on a project on AdonisJs and Lucid ORM where i need to show a chart with user registration count grouped by every month `(created_at -> month name)` for the last year.

I did this query in Laravel eloquent but didn't find a solution for how to do this query in Lucid.

Please note: I'm using PostgreSQL and CockroachDB

#### User table columns

```
id | username | email | created_at | updated_at
```

#### PostgreSQL query

```sql
SELECT
  to_char(date_trunc('month', created_at), 'YYYY, Month') AS created_month,
  COUNT(id) AS total_registrations,
FROM users
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', created_at)
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', created_at)
```

I really need to know how I can do the same using Lucid ORM.

I'll appreciate any help from you. Best regards!